# Phoenix auth with js, "put_flash" not showing up

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I made few customizations to phoenix form submit, using jquery to prevent reload(since my login form is in modal), form:

```
<form id="loginForm" role="form">
 <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="<%= get_csrf_token() %>">
...
```

jQuery

```
<script> document.getElementById("loginbutton").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  $.ajax({
        url:'/auth/identity/callback',
        type:'post',
        data:$('#loginForm').serialize()

});</script>
```

And AuthController, that should re-render main page, it sends new html of entire site in callback but it doesn't re-render actual site:

```
{:error, reason} ->       
    conn
    |> put_flash(:error, "Could not authenticate. Error: #{reason}")       
    |> render(Final.PageView, "landingapp.html", current_user: current_user, current_auths: auths(current_user))
```

Could jquerys preventdefault() be reason :error flash isn't showing? What am I missing?

Comment: Why won't you just use json for example and change the page accordingly instead of trying to rerender it? Just send `{"error": "some reason"}` back and handle that on the client side, show an error or whatnot

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell you're basically breaking the mechanism you want to use. `put_flash` function puts data in to `flash session scope`, which you can access in the render. But you're not loading the page again and you're using ajax. `preventDefault()` makes the page not to reload (which you probably want).

You can either use it as you suppose with ajax and only handle data as json or reload page per request. But please don't use ajax to fetch new html and swap it....

I don't even know why have you used jQuery in the first place.